# iOS tableview refresh issue

Tags: ios, xml, crash, reachability, sigabrt

My application uses a table that is populated by a dynamic xml feed. I am also using the pull to refresh code written by Grant Paul to reload the table with new content, if there is some. Thirdly, I am using Apple's Reachability to determine internet connectivity when reloading the table. My problem is this; If I open the application WITH internet connection, then while the app is running, shut of my internet connection, I then pull to refresh the application and it crashes. Something is happening when the app is switching between Reachable and NotReachable. Below is my code. The app fails with a Thread 6: signal SIGABRT on this line:             TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];

Here is the error code:

```
2012-10-02 14:00:03.715 FireCom[2229:1517] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2d63012 0x21a0e7e 0x2d050b4 0x603f 0xd810d5 0xd81034 0x96213557 0x961fdcee)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Here is the Reachability code:

```
- (void)loadCallList
{
Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.apple.com"];
NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

switch (netStatus)
{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        NSLog(@"Access Not Available");

        [pull finishedLoading];
        [self displayInternetMessage];

        break;
    }

    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        NSLog(@"Reachable WWAN");

        // Parse HTML for random ID and create XML link

        NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.wccca.com/PITS/"];
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theURL];
        xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];
        NSArray *elements = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//input[@id='hidXMLID']//@value"];
        TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
        TFHppleElement *child = [element.children objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *idValue = [child content];

        NSString *idwithxml = [idValue stringByAppendingFormat:@".xml"];
        NSString *url = @"http://www.wccca.com/PITS/xml/fire_data_";
        NSString *finalurl = [url stringByAppendingString:idwithxml];

        xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:finalurl];

        if (xmlParser.calls.count == 0)
        {
            self.headerHeight = 0.0;
            UIAlertView *noCalls = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Current Calls"
                                                              message:@"There are no current 9-1-1 calls in Clackamas or Washington County."
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [noCalls show];
            [noCalls release];
        }
        else
        {
            self.headerHeight = 45.0;
        }

        [callsTableView reloadData];
        [pull finishedLoading];

        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        NSLog(@"Reachable WiFi");

        // Parse HTML for random ID and create XML link

        NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.wccca.com/PITS/"];
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theURL];
        xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];
        NSArray *elements = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//input[@id='hidXMLID']//@value"];
        TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
        TFHppleElement *child = [element.children objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *idValue = [child content];

        NSString *idwithxml = [idValue stringByAppendingFormat:@".xml"];
        NSString *url = @"http://www.wccca.com/PITS/xml/fire_data_";
        NSString *finalurl = [url stringByAppendingString:idwithxml];

        xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:finalurl];

        if (xmlParser.calls.count == 0)
        {
            self.headerHeight = 0.0;

            UIAlertView *noCalls = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Current Calls"
                                                              message:@"There are no current 9-1-1 calls in Clackamas or Washington County."
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [noCalls show];
            [noCalls release];
        }
        else
        {
            self.headerHeight = 45.0;
        }

        [callsTableView reloadData];
        [pull finishedLoading];

        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code assumes that your `elements` array will have data.  You should first check if nil or count == 0 and add logic to handle a 'no data' scenario.

Comment: the elements array will ALWAYS have data. it will never be empty.

Comment: And if `xpathParser` can't find any elements with an id of `hidXMLID`?  I think the answer lies in the data.  You aren't getting back what you think you are.  Your issues is pretty cut-and-dry.  Elements doesn't have anything in it, thus you get the error.

Comment: I have NSLogged what I am getting back for xpathParser when the app crashes and it is indeed getting what it is suppose to, the ID from the HTML code.

Comment: So, you are saying that you NSLog the elements array and there is data in it?  If there are elements in it, then I think you mean to say that your error is with `TFHppleElement *child = [element.children objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: Think about this logically...the error is saying that there is no data in your array, but you say that there is.  Investigate the following: 1) Why does the error indicate a mutable array when elements is not mutable 2) Double check that element has any children.

Comment: The point is, with NO internet connection why is the application reading case ReachableViaWiFi? It shouldn't even look at that code... That is why it is failing.

Comment: I think we got on a wrong sidetrack, the application works fine with internet connection. When i switch to no internet, it crashes because for some reason because it is still reading ReachableViaWiFi.

Comment: I see.  Problem is I believe that you can be connected to your WiFi without internet.

Comment: Oh that makes sense because the iPhone simulator constantly displays the Wifi icon up in the left hand side, even when I shut off my internet. That makes sense now. So I need to go into settings in the iPhone Simulator and turn wifi off and check it that way....

Comment: And I need to add an if statement like you said before to check if it returns data due to the iphone being connected, but no internet. Thanks. It all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your problem.

```
NSArray *elements = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//input[@id='hidXMLID']//@value"];
TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
TFHppleElement *child = [element.children objectAtIndex:0];
```

You can't assume `elements` has a count of at least on 1.

---

**Update**

Maybe try something like

```
NSArray *elements = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//input[@id='hidXMLID']//@value"];
if (elements.count < 1) {
    // Any needed cleanup
    break;
}

TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
TFHppleElement *child = [element.children objectAtIndex:0];
```

as a fast way out.

Comment: like I said above, the elements array will always have data! it parse's an HTML file to look for an ID and then creates a URL that the XML Parser can use to parse.